# Remove one part from AttributedText in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a`UILabel` which has attributed text set like

> Good morning \n Alex

It shows as 2 lines in `UILabel`. I want to show this and after few seconds remove the Good morning part and just show the Alex part.

Is this possible to do?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `NSTimer` - [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer) for number of seconds and after that timer fires, you would simply change the text of the `UILabel`

`textLabel.attributedText = "Alex"`

inside of the completion block of the `NSTimer`

Answer (score 0):

You could use GCD

```
let delayInSeconds = 4.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {

     textLabel.attributedText = "Alex"


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and pass your delay and update the attributed text:-

```
func delay(_ delay: Double, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
            deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
    }

func updateAttributedText() {
  delay(1) { 
   self.textLabel.attributedText = NSAttributed(string: "Alex")
  }
}
```

Comment: `self.textLabel.attributedText = "Alex"` That line should show at least a warning (if not a crash), because you are assigning a String where you should assign a NSAttributedString.